# How to find combination of numbers in set that maximize closeness to target value

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm looking for a solution of how to find the subset of numbers within a larger set that gets as close as possible to a target number. So for instance, I have a set of values:

```
   c(55.14, 26.22, 76.69, 37.77, 32.7, 48.71, 7.59, 21.37, 33.54, 3.95, 16.41, 
20.56, 24.74, 26.5, 4.72, 32.99, 130.15, 27.27, 20.56, 41.21, 13, 16.41, 88.25, 
1.95, 68.2, 34.3, 51.75, 8.93, 8.38, 30.45, 34.89, 42.91, 19.42, 13.62, 9.73, 
20.86, 21.5, 37.46, 14.4, 26.61, 55.31, 24.03)
```

And my target is 1262.2.

How can I find the subset of values in the full set that minimizes the difference between my target, 1262.2, and the sum of the subset?

Comment: If you know how many numbers you want to choose from your set `x`, use `combn(x, n)` - this gives all possible sets from x with n numbers in it, then sum those and find the minimum. Repeat for any n to find the minimum (prepare to wait!).

Comment: @Remko - according to some quick calculations - `sum(sapply(1:length(x), function(y) choose(length(x),y) ))` where `x` is the above vector, that will be `4398046511103` possible combinations to check. That's 4 trillion with change. As you note, OP should probably have some restrictions to make this manageable.

Comment: Do you need many combinations or only one is fine? A quick fix would be to sort all the elements in the set and run a for loop that sums all the elements in the set till it is less than your target. It is a quick fix but will return the result in less time than checking all combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `v` be the vector of values shown in the question.

Let `x` be an unknown vector of the same length containing 0-1 variables.

Then run these two integer linear programs over `x` choosing the solution from the one whose objective is closest to 1262.2.  (Here * means the inner product.)

```
max(v*x) such that v*x <= 1262.2

min(v*x) such that v*x >= 1262.2
```

Using Rglpk for the first one we get this and since we achieved 1262.2 exactly we don't need to bother with the second integer linear program:

```
library(Rglpk)

ans <- Rglpk_solve_LP(v, t(v), "<=", 1262.2, max = TRUE, types = "B")
```

giving:

```
> ans[1:3]
$optimum
[1] 1262.2

$solution
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$status
[1] 0
```

**Note** The first integer linear program is known as a knapsack problem and we can solve it using `knapsack` in adagio.

```
library(adadgio)

v100 <- as.integer(100 * v)
knapsack(v100, v100, 126220L)
```

(Although not mentioned on its help page, knapsack requires integer arguments.)

Comment: And this is relatively quick? This seems like magic to me, but clearly I don't understand linear programming at all.

Comment: Yes.  It is pretty much instantaneous.

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck. This is a great solution. When I add up the values that are left over, I do not get $1262.2. Am I missing something about which values to take out?

Comment: nevermind @G.Grothendieck. I took out two of the incorrect numbers. thank you again!